# IKEA table problem

Tags: installation, table

I got this table and legs from IKEA, and I have no idea how to assemble them.

The legs are like this:

[image]

The table has screws on one side

[image]

Comment: Which table is it? (what is the name on the box)

Comment: yeah, you really need to tell us the model. also, you should be able to find instructions online at ikea's website at http://www.ikea.com/ms/en_US/customer_service/assembly_instructions.html.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I hadn't realized that. I'll take not of that for future postings.

Comment: -1 Product specific question that has a narrow audience, and furniture assembly is a gray area that may be off topic for this site. This question should probably be closed, but I'm waiting for others to agree/disagree before taking action.

Comment: @BMitch Please just delete it, you have my blessings. I got the help I needed.

Comment: actually, @BMitch, i agree with you, too. Comments and answers are fine and help OP, but the overall audience just isn't there for this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a product specific furniture assembly request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks to me like you have a [GALANT leg](http://www.ikea.com/kw/en/catalog/products/40057457/). From IKEA's website

> The legs shall be fitted on to the frame before the table top is put in place.

If you only have the table and legs, you may not have everything you need.

Based on instructions found at [the customer service site linked to by alt](http://www.ikea.com/ms/en_US/customer_service/assembly_instructions.html), you need to put the legs onto the frame bar piece, then put the screw through the top of the frame into the hole in the leg. Then attach the table to the frame with additional screws (smaller than the ones in your picture).

Comment: Oh, damn! You're right. I didn't pick up the third piece for the table because I thought it was an auxiliary part. I'll need to go buy it, I guess.

Comment: I'm surprised that Ikea let you take only a part of the whole thing. In my experience, they check to see if you've got everything that you've paid for. But hey, as long as this works out OK in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Going from those pictures, it kind of looks like you drive the screws through the holes in the table surface into the legs. :)

Comment: The table only has holes on one side, while the other side is completely clear.